# ImportError: No module named datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

from datasets import dataset_utils ImportError: No module named datasets.
when i am writing this in python sript.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from datasets import dataset_utils
slim = tf.contrib.slim
```

But i am getting error.

```
from datasets import dataset_utils
ImportError: No module named datasets
```

I found this solution 
[How can jupyter access a new tensorflow module installed in the right path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811840/how-can-jupyter-access-a-new-tensorflow-module-installed-in-the-right-path)
 I did the same and i have dataset packages at path anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. Still i am getting same error.

Comment: what is your `PYTHONPATH` in your env?

Comment: What is `datasets`? Did you mean the `dataset` module?

Answer (score 38):

```
pip install datasets
```

I solved it this way.

Answer (score 8):

You can find the folder address on your device and append it to system path.

```
import sys  
sys.path.append(r"D:\Python35\models\slim\datasets"); import dataset_utils
```

You'll need to do the same with 'nets' and 'preprocessing'

```
sys.path.append(r"D:\Python35\models\slim\nets"); import vgg
sys.path.append(r"D:\Python35\models\slim\preprocessing"); import vgg_preprocessing
```

Comment: @Mad Physicist  how did you get the code inside a box??

Comment: Indent by four spaces, or click on the button `{}` in the editor after you highlight the code.

Comment: If you want to inline it, the `{}` button will do that as long as you don't select entire lines, or you can just use back-ticks (`) around the code.

Comment: Also, among all the times I have corrected other people's code, you are the first one that has asked me anything about it, so good on you. I know that it can be hard to find the docs sometimes and the editor is a bit fancy for first-time users, so I appreciate you making the effort to learn.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didn't know about the {[code here]}.  Upvoted

Answer (score 3):

Datasets is present in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim/datasets
Since 'models' are not installable from pip (at the time of writing), they are not available in python load paths by default. So either we copy them or manually add to the path.
Here is how I setup env before running the code:

```
# git clone or wget
wget https://github.com/tensorflow/models/archive/master.zip -O models.zip 
unzip models.zip
# add it to Python PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD/models-master/slim
# now we are good to call `python mytensorflow.py`
```

Comment: Page not found for the hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

It's using the datasets package in the TF-slim image models library, which is in:

git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models/

Having done that though, in order to import the module as shown in the example on the slim image page, empty **init**.py have to be added to the models and models/slim directories.

Answer (score 0):

go to https://github.com/nschaetti/EchoTorch/releases and download the latest release

install the latest release from the downloaded file (202006291 is the latest version at the moment):
`$pip install ./EchoTorch-202006291.zip`

test it out using narma10_esn.py (other examples may have some issues)

you may still need to install some more python packages not listed in the requirements file but it works once you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on one of my computers but not the others.  This was a windows computer.  I had already tried "pip install datasets" to no effect.  Turns out that package only can be found if you have python installed globally for "all users".  If you have it installed only for your own user account (which is the default for the python installer on windows) datasets won't be findable even though you can manually locate the folder it is installed in.

Comment: I'm having this problem now, can you list the steps you used to fix it, please?

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me (do not forget to use pip3 in ipython / Google
> colab), then first import the entire datasets lib

```
pip3 install datasets
import datasets
from datasets import dataset_utils
```

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, don't select to run the code, choose to run the python program!

Comment: Where is Visual Studio mentioned in the question?