# ImportError: No module named 'datasets'

Tags: django, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm using inception_v3 inside my django app. 
I have cloned this repository: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git), and have made a **incep.py** file and written a function `**generator():**` as instructed on this page: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb).
I have changed the inception_v1 to v3 in the code.
When called the **incep.py** returns the tags generated from the given image.
I have cloned the git repository inside my django app folder and have also made a incepTest.py file where I'm calling the incep.py file. I'm facing the "ImportError: No module named 'datasets' " error.
I have already tried the solutions provided here: [ImportError: No module named datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319101/importerror-no-module-named-datasets), but I'm still getting the error of no module named "datasets".

I have imported the incep.py file as follows:

```
from models.research.slim.incep import generator
```

Also I have placed a blank **init**.py file in every working folder of models.
Any help would be helpful.

Comment: From which folder are you running it? Here is the [datasets module](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/datasets) you're missing.

Comment: i have to run from within my django's app folder.

Comment: i'm receiving the same error with this datasets file also. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/datasets