# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.datasets'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using Python 3.6.8 on Windows 10
I installed **tensorflow, keras, and utils** using **pip**.

`pip install tensorflow` and it installs the version **2.0.0**
`pip install keras` and it installs the version **2.3.1**
`pip install utils` but it does not show what version I have installed.

This is my header:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import model_from_json, load_model
import numpy as np
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import os
import random
import string

from utils.datasets import get_labels
from utils.inference import apply_offsets
from utils.inference import load_detection_model
from utils.preprocessor import preprocess_input
```

This is my error:

> from utils.datasets import get_labels
>      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.datasets'

Why am I getting this error? And how to fix it? BTW The code was written by a previous programmer and I need to modify it. But I can't even run it. not so good in python tho. i'm just getting started to it.

All my google search are all purple but I can't seem to find any solutions.

**EDIT**

The suggested answer ([ImportError: No module named datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319101/importerror-no-module-named-datasets)) does not satisfy my needs. I am having trouble on utils module. because when I comment out the line `from utils.datasets import get_labels`

The error is on the next line:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.inference'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319101/importerror-no-module-named-datasets)

Comment: @abhikumar22 no it does not. My error is from `utils.datasets` module not on `datasets` module. That's what I thought

Comment: then try to reinstall it

Comment: I've already done it many times T_T
I've also tried to reinstall everything including `pyhton`

Comment: Utils is not a standard package, it is specific to the code you are trying to run, what exact code is this?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It is for emotion detection. do you have a link how to use utils?

Comment: You did not understand my comment, utils is a package specific to your code, you have to tell us what it is, not us. Its probably a package inside your source code (which we do not have).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utils model what the code your provided want to import is the part of the [oarriaga/face_classification](https://github.com/oarriaga/face_classification/tree/master/src) project.

The pip installed `utils` modul is **quite different** package, so you should not have installed via `pip`. Your code try to import moduls from this package, but it obviously has no such moduls. That is why the error messages.

So what you have to do is `pip uninstall utils` and then if your project directory structure is complete, the above code will import the `face_classification` package's moduls.

Comment: I found `utils` folder in the directory. thanks! i did uninstall utils and now it's working. I am just having trouble with the deprecated codes in the package.