# How to solve the problem with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'" on osx

Tags: python, dataset

I had installed dataset module already, but when I import it, it keeps showing that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'". I'm using python 3.7.10 with osx 10.15.

```
import dataset

db = dataset.connect('mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1/dataname')
table = db['users']
table.insert(dict(userid='a1344134'))
```

Comment: ^Did you check with the environment that you installed on? Is it the same kernel?

Comment: is this solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319101/importerror-no-module-named-datasets

Comment: It looks like it's: No module named 'MySQLdb'. I try to install mysqldb, but it seems it took away from python 3.6, and even though I try to install mysql-client by brew, it shows: Error: No formulae found in taps.